# How can I get array json value from Firebase remote-config ?(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I use Firebase Remote Config to compare app's version to update, but I can't get Remote Config value.

How can I get value like array json with swift?

Here is My value

```
[
{
"version": "1.0.4",
"status": "2",
"text": "Fix Error"
}
]
```

And here is my code

Get value:

```
class ConstraintValues {
static let shared = ConstraintValues()
init() {
    RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().setDefaults(["a":"b" as NSObject])
    let debugSettings = RemoteConfigSettings()
    RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().configSettings = debugSettings
}
func fetch(completetion:@escaping ( _ stringarray:String?)->()) {
    RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().fetch(withExpirationDuration: 0) { (status, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            completetion(nil)
            return
        }
        RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().activate()
        let rc = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().configValue(forKey: "VERSION")

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: rc.dataValue, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:String]

            guard let dictionary1 = json["version"] else {return }
            guard let dictionary2 = json["text"] else {return }
            guard let dictionary3 = json["status"] else {return }
            completetion(dictionary1)
            completetion(dictionary2)
            completetion(dictionary3)
        }
        catch let error{
            print(error)
            completetion(nil)
        }

    }
}}
```

Check Version:

```
func checkversion(controller:UIViewController){
    ConstraintValues.shared.fetch { (version) in
        let cversion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! NSString//localversion
         let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")
        let appStore = version//newversion
        //Compare
        let versionCompare = cversion.compare(appStore! as String, options: .numeric)
        if versionCompare == .orderedSame {
            print("same version")
        } else if versionCompare == .orderedAscending {

            let alertc = UIAlertController(title: "UPDATE!!", message: "New Version: \(version!)", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let alertaction = UIAlertAction(title: "Update", style: .default, handler: { (ok) in
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                } else {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
                }
            })
            alertc.addAction(alertaction)
            controller.present(alertc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if versionCompare == .orderedDescending {

        }
    }
}
```

I can take "version": "1.0.4",but"text" can't get.
How should I do for this method?

Answer (score 1):

As you're using a JSON object, I would recommend using SwiftyJSON here.

install [SwiftyJSON](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftyJSON) in your project

Then import `SwiftyJSON` at the top of your file

Your code should look like the following

```
import Firebase
import SwiftyJSON

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
        
    var remoteConfig: RemoteConfig!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
        let settings = RemoteConfigSettings()
        settings.minimumFetchInterval = 0
        remoteConfig.configSettings = settings
        
        var remoteConfigDefaults = [String: NSObject]()        
        let testArr: NSArray = []
        remoteConfigDefaults["VERSION"] = testStr
        remoteConfig.setDefaults(remoteConfigDefaults)        
        
        remoteConfig.fetch() { (status, error) -> Void in
            if status == .success {
                print("Config fetched!")
                self.remoteConfig.activate() { (error) in
                    // ...
                }
            } else {
                print("Config not fetched")
                print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No error available.")")
            }
          
            let version = self.remoteConfig.configValue(forKey: "VERSION").jsonValue            
            let json = JSON(version)            
            print(json[0]["version"], json[0]["status"], json[0]["text"])
            
        }
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jsonValue is now directly supported, there is no need for `JSONDecoder().decode`:

```
enum RemoteConfigKey: String {
        case countries_to_log
}

init() {
        remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
        let appDefaults: [String: Any?] = [
            RemoteConfigKey.countries_to_log.rawValue: ["country": ["DE"]]
        ]
        remoteConfig.setDefaults(appDefaults as? [String: NSObject])
        fetchValues()
}

var countries_to_log: [String: [String]] {
        RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().configValue(forKey: RemoteConfigKey.countries_to_log.rawValue).jsonValue as! [String : [String]]
}
```